# work with UIPagecontrol using NSTimer in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, uipagecontrol

I am trying to add the UIPagecontrol using `NSTimer` for images sliding.
but not able to get it.
I have tried something which is given below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pagecontrol: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgview: UIImageView!

     var tTime: Timer!
     var index = 0
     var items = ["1.png","11.png","111.png","1111.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configurePageControl()
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        self.pagecontrol.numberOfPages = items.count
        self.pagecontrol.currentPage = 0
        self.pagecontrol.tintColor = UIColor.red
        self.pagecontrol.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.pagecontrol.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green
    }

    @objc func update()  {
        index = index + 1
    }
}
```

If anyone helps,Would be great.Thank in advance.

Comment: What's the problem here? You didn't implement any code to change the image! If you don't know how to set image of the `UIImageView` you should ask about that, not about `Timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
@objc func update()  {
        index = index + 1

    }
```

function to

```
@objc func update()  {
    index = index + 1

    if index >= items.count {
        index = 0
    }
    imgview.image = UIImage(named: items[index])
    pagecontrol.currentPage = index
}
```

And it should work.